# Web Start app exception on launch

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, java-web-start, jnlp, maven-webstart-plugin

I have a problem when launch my web start app. I take a ClassNotFoundException by an external Jar, but this jar is correctly defined in my jnlp and his path it's correctly accessible too.

This is the trace of the exception:

```
13:05:05.848 [Thread-18] ERROR c.o.b.xml.XMLApplicationBuilder - Error instantiating: 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor25.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.ontimize.builder.xml.XMLApplicationBuilder.instance(XMLApplicationBuilder.java:602) [ontimize-core-5.8.0.jar:na]
    at com.ontimize.builder.xml.XMLApplicationBuilder.instance(XMLApplicationBuilder.java:588) [ontimize-core-5.8.0.jar:na]
    at com.ontimize.builder.xml.XMLApplicationBuilder.buildFormManager(XMLApplicationBuilder.java:737) [ontimize-core-5.8.0.jar:na]
    at com.ontimize.builder.xml.XMLApplicationBuilder.buildApplication(XMLApplicationBuilder.java:383) [ontimize-core-5.8.0.jar:na]
    at com.ontimize.gui.ApplicationLauncher$StartedThread.run(ApplicationLauncher.java:74) [ontimize-core-5.8.0.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ontimize/gui/BasicInteractionManager
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.ontimize.gui.manager.BaseFormManager.init(BaseFormManager.java:485) ~[ontimize-core-5.8.0.jar:na]
    at com.ontimize.gui.FormManager.init(FormManager.java:321) ~[ontimize-core-5.8.0.jar:na]
    at com.ontimize.gui.manager.BaseFormManager.<init>(BaseFormManager.java:410) ~[ontimize-core-5.8.0.jar:na]
    at com.ontimize.gui.FormManager.<init>(FormManager.java:282) ~[ontimize-core-5.8.0.jar:na]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ontimize.gui.BasicInteractionManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
```

And this is my jnlp:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://host2:8085/gestiontributaria/" href="launch.jnlp">
    <security>
        <all-permissions />
    </security>
    <resources>
        <java version="1.7+" initial-heap-size="32m" max-heap-size="256m" />
        <jar href="webstart/gestiontributaria-client-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" main="true" download="eager" />
        <jar href="webstart/gestiontributaria-common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" download="eager"/>
        <jar href="webstart/ontimize-core-5.8.0.jar" download="lazy"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="org.gestiontributaria.client.ClientLauncher">
        <argument>org/gestiontributaria/client/conf/labels.xml</argument>
        <argument>org/gestiontributaria/client/clientapplication.xml</argument>
        <argument>-conf</argument>
        <argument>org/gestiontributaria/client/conf/defaultXMLConfigurationParameters.xml</argument>
        <argument>-Dcom.ontimize.locator.ReferenceLocator.Port=49015</argument>
        <argument>-Dcom.ontimize.locator.ReferenceLocator.Hostname=servidoraplicaciones2</argument>
        <argument>-Dcom.ontimize.util.rmitunneling.cgipath=/gestiontributaria/rmitunneling/rmi</argument>
        <argument>-Dcom.ontimize.util.rmitunneling.port=8085</argument>
        <argument>-Dcom.ontimize.util.rmitunneling.debug=false</argument>
        <argument>-Dcom.ontimize.gui.lafclassname=com.ontimize.plaf.OntimizeLookAndFeel</argument>
        <argument>-Dcom.ontimize.gui.lafstyle=com/ontimize/plaf/style/brown_style.css</argument>
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

All the jars are in gestiontributaria/webstart/ and all was signed with the same certified. My jnlp are in gestiontributaria/.

ontimize-core-5.8.0.jar was downloaded, I can see it on resources at java control panel.

I deploy the war with tomcat 8.5.

anybody have an idea about this issue?

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0). BTW - why is `ontimize-core-5.8.0.jar` marked for `lazy` download, have you tried changing it to `eager`? (It should work either way, but maybe there is a bug in the JVM that would be averted if download is `eager`.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @AndrewThompson . I check with JaNeLa and it is all right (I'm going to upload captures on Friday, because I don't have access to production environmet at the moment, sorry). The lazy load marker on ontimize-core-5.8.0.jar it is a mistake in my question, but at the begin I have tried with eager too, without successful. Do you have any other idea?